# SQL Server: How do I update dates so that they are two months prior?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could anyone advice me on how I could run an UPDATE statement in SQL Server to take a number of given DATETIME fields and deduct two months from them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET DateField1 = DATEADD(mm, -2, DateField1)
WHERE .....
```

Answer (score 2):

use [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) with first argument as 'm' or 'mm' and second as '-2' and third one being your date